# RedirectToRoute in Ajax Controller symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have a controller that I call with Ajax.
Inside this controller I have a condition, like

```
if($a == 10){
    return $this->redirectToRoute('form_finish');
}
```

But when the condition is satisfited, I don't have the redirect

Comment: It should redirect user to another page or should redirect just ajax call? 
If first option = return json and handle in JS side, if second you can forward action using "forward" method in controller. It's not a redirect, but you will get result of method under "form_finish" route.

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski I want to  redirect with change page / url

Comment: So you should handle redirect response in Ajax call. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski thanks, I'd like to Avoid to do in Javascript, Can I do it ?

Comment: So why you're using Ajax...(?) I think there is no way w/o JS.

Comment: I manage the page with Ajax, but i'd like to use redirect through controller. Thanks !

Comment: solution 1: dont use ajax  / solution 2: redirect with js

Answer (score 2):

You call the controller in ajax but do you manage the response.

You have to redirect from the browser if the condition is satisfied or handle the ajax response and load the content in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing something like this :

In controller i put the redirect handler in Jsonresponse :

```
//return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_logout');
$response = new JsonResponse(array(
'route' => $this->get('router')->generate('fos_user_security_logout'),
'message'    => 'You may choose on option'));
return $response;
```

And in ajax

```
success: function(response,xhr){
//This is for the redrection in front page
if(response.route) { window.location.href=response.route;}
```

Hope it helps someone